# How can translate this statement in C to assembly language?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, optimization, x86

(C)

```
d = b * 7
```

(Assembly language)

(1)

```
movl b, %eax
movl $7, %ebx
mull %ebx    
movl %eax, d  
movl %edx, e
```

if 32bit integer type is multiplied with same type, it needs 64bit space for return value. so i use eax register(for lower 32bit) and edx register(for upper 32bit).

(2)

```
movl b, %eax
movl %eax, %ebx
sall $2, %eax      
subl %ebx, %eax  
movl %eax, d
```

in (2) case, i dont have idea how can control upper 32bit return value. pls tell me some idea...

Comment: In C, `b * 7` is not widening.  If you have `uint32_t b`, you'll get a `uint32_t` result.  Assigning to a wider type will merely zero-extend that 32-bit result.  So `imul $7, b, %eax` will work just fine.  Look at real compiler output on https://godbolt.org/z/rhPWhc for 32 or 64-bit code.  If you did want to implement `b * 7ULL`, you'd normally just use `mul`, but clarify in your question what types your C variables have, and whether you actually need widening or if you just need to implement what some expression means in C.

Comment: Also, see https://godbolt.org/z/6rxc3x - turns out GCC *does* use an insane sequence of `shld` / `shl` / `sub` / `sbb` to do the `(x<<3) - x` way for a widening multiply, unless you use a tune option like `-mtune=skylake` for a CPU it knows has a fast multiplier, then it uses `mul`.  Pretty sure 32-bit `mul` is better on most mainstream CPUs that are still relevant, and never *that* much worse.  GCC's sequence may at least 1 wasted `mov` instructions, vs. using an `lea` to copy-and-shift.